# Blackberry App crashes in between

Tags: blackberry

I've developed a very big application for Blackberry Curve 8900. It contains so many Bitmaps and they are coming from URL through Parsing. I am using wifi connection. The app hangs many times. Even it fails to start.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. Actually my app is too big. And contains lots of coding files. How can I share this?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question for us to help you.

Comment: Sometimes my app works perfectly. But when I test in another device or on another network, it fails. Is this happening because of slow server? Or any other network problem or memory issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to download the images in the event thread (UI thread)? All lengthy ,network operations should be run in a separate thread.

Comment: Yes I am running all these things in different threads. For Parsing, I am using two separate threads, one for parsing the data and another for displaying loading screen.